How to make PowerShell Active Directory cmdlets working
I tried to use the Get-ADUser PowerShell Active Directory cmdlet, but am getting:
PS C:\> Get-ADUser
Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.

All my search results point to the following solution:

install RSAT: Active Directory Domain Services and Lightweight Directory Tools
verify that the Active Directory module is available by importing it

However, this is what I'm getting:
PS C:\> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.ActiveDirectory.DS-LDS.Tools


Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False


PS C:\> Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
Import-Module : The specified module 'ActiveDirectory' was not loaded because no valid module file was found
in any module directory.

PS C:\> Get-ADUser
Get-ADUser : The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.

The Get-ADUser PowerShell cmdlet works in one of our machines, and I want to make it works on other machines too.

Which Windows version? Which PowerShell version? Are you doing this from an elevated prompt?

The cmdlet does not work with a shared directory (Active Directory) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#notes

Yes, I'm doing this from an elevated prompt, @iRon (Note that it works in antoher machines), and it's on Microsoft Windows Server 2022 Standard with PSVersion
5.1.20348.2400.

The cmdlet does not work with an Active Directory snapshot @jdweng.

snap shot may be on one machine and the other machines the directory is a link.

"snap shot may be on one machine and the other machines the directory is a link". How to verify @jdweng? Anyway, I don't think it even matters, as it should not affect installation, on a normal machine, not AD itself.

I'm just reporting what the online manual says.  It doesn't say what error message you get when it fails.  Sometimes error messages are misleading.
